# axios - OPTIONS 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch, axios

I'm trying to get data from an authorized API in a Reactjs app and I'm still getting that 401(Unauthorized) error, also 'OPTIONS' request keeps popping up instead of GET request.

```
const api_call = await axios.get(`api-link`, {'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept", 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : "*", headers: {'Authorization': "bearer API-auth"}});

const response= await api_call.json();
console.log(response);
```

Comment: Can you say what API is? You only need `axios.get('link', {headers: {'Authorization: Bearer token'}}`. Have you tried with CAPS B?

Comment: You might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047548/response-for-preflight-does-not-have-http-ok-status-in-angular helpful; basically the server shouldn’t require authentication for a CORS preflight request (the OPTIONS sent automatically as part of this request).

Comment: CORS is not something you handle from the frontend. It should be handled through the server you are making a call to, namely, the API.