# "Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status." 500 in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

im getting this error in my angular 6, how do i go about it?

"Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status." 500 in angular 6
 *"Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status." 500 in angular 6 *

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047548/response-for-preflight-does-not-have-http-ok-status-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

change your back-end to not require authentication for the OPTIONS method when handling the login url