# How to solve Angular CORS Errors when using API

Tags: angular

I was working on E-commerce project and it was working well and there is no problems, when I deleted the products table and create it again with the same migration page code it worked well from Postman but in angular when I run the project it shows this error
[image: The Errors]

Comment: In the api you need to configure the allowed origins. In this case you need to add the angular localhost and port to the api. This is more a question depending on the language/framework your API is using.

Comment: I am working with laravel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52047548/response-for-preflight-does-not-have-http-ok-status-in-angular)

Comment: no it doesn't bro

Comment: Which port your api is hosted on can you try hitting on that
Eg . http://localhost:<port>/mobitech/...